# is there a way to protect subtitle file from stolen?

Tags: jwplayer, caption, subtitle, jwplayer6, closed-captions

Recently, we have some problem because our subtitle file has been stolen, 
we are using `JWPlayer 6.12`.

So, has anyone had experience to deal with this situation please share!!!

Thank you.

**Sorry for my bad English.**

Comment: The files are loaded client side, so it can't be totally protected. May I suggest embedding your code using a tool like this? - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

Comment: even you encrypt the source code, when you `inspect element` the page you still can see everything, so it's useless.

Comment: Right, the player is client side, so anything client side can be taken, basically. This just makes it harder for most people.

Comment: The only way to be absolutely sure that no one will take your image, video, subtitle file, etc., etc., is not to put it on a web page. Everything that happens in a browser is first downloaded to the browser, then displayed. Your visitors are not viewing your content remotely, as if through binoculars. And once something is on the visitor's PC, he can grab it, one way or another.

Comment: “our subtitle file has been stolen” — what do you mean by “stolen”? Are you saying that you put video subtitles up on the web, so that anyone in the world with an internet connection can access them, but you don’t want *certain* people to be able to access them?

Comment: I have found a way to do that using Wowza server.
http://[wowza-ip]:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzacaptionfile=sample.srt
This is my feedback hope it help other who use Wowza + JWplayer

Answer (score 0):

I will do it this way

```
var sub_base = "http://www.example.com/secret-sub-floder/";
```

above code hidden in external javascript file

and this code in jw player setup

```
  tracks: [{ 
    file: sub_base + "Birdman.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.CHI.srt", 
    label: 'English', 
    kind: 'captions' 
  }],
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think this will escape Google Inspect  Elements -> Network tab.

Comment: @Neo are you using html5 version or Flash?

Comment: I use `jwplayer` (streaming with Wowza) which is support both HTML5 and Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do that using Wowza server.

```
http://[wowza-ip]:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzacaptionfile=sample.‌​srt
```

This is my feedback hope it help other who use Wowza + JWplayer